# accessing ant properties in groovy taskdef gives Null Pointer Exception

Tags: ant, groovy

I am trying to execute following code but I am getting null pointer exception.

```
 <property name="from" value="from"/>
            <property name="to" value="to"/>


            <taskdef name="groovy"
                classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy"
                classpath="G:\Tibco_Training\groovy-binary-1.8.5\groovy-all-1.6.5.jar" />

            <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>
        <groovy>
                class MoveDir extends org.apache.tools.ant.Task {
                    //def from = 'from'
                    //def to = 'to'
                    public void execute() { 
                        new File(properties.from).eachFileMatch ~/.*/, { file ->
                        file.renameTo(new File(properties.to , file.getName()))
                        println "Moving file: $file.name from: " + from + "  to: " + to }
                    }
        }

                project.addTaskDefinition('movedir', MoveDir)
            </groovy>

            <movedir />
```

If I don't  use ant properties in groovy then the code works fine, but when I use ant properties for specifying directories, then it give null pointer exception. Am I passing wrong values or wrong syntax is the cause.

Comment: Posting the exception would probably help, it's hard to debug anecdotes

Answer (score 0):

Wrong syntax, you have to use `properties.'to'` and `properties.'from'`

Comment: can you please tell me how to pass argument to the taskdef. for example here in this case if I need to have movedir as:  <movedir from="${fromdir}" to="${to}"/>

Comment: import the groovy taskdef, then create a macrodef powered by groovy with the attributes from and to and let it do all the things you need to be done..